# How can I generate nested fieldsets using Zend Form 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form2, zend-form-fieldset

[image]

Hi, there! I wanna create a form like the above image through the zend framework 2. The input fields will be like:

```
1. dependent_features[0], 2. dependent_features[1] etc
```

and their corresponding independent features like:

```
1. independent_features[0][], 2. independent_features[1][] etc.
```

Now, how can I generate this kind of form with the collection input fields as well as its validations?

Comment: What have you tried? We won't write your code for you, and we can't help until the problem is narrowed down a little.

Comment: Documentation available for fieldset in ZF2 all around the web, as my mate above said, what did you tried, but first where did you search before asking

Comment: Sorry for the question, but I've tried to generate through the zf2 collection, but nothing fruitful is happened. The field 'independent_features' is directly dependent on the 'dependent_features' with index-wise, i.e. 'independent_features[__KEY__][]' is directly dependent on 'dependent_features[__KEY__]'. So, I had no idea how I generate this kind of form through the collection element. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/collections/#creating-fieldsets

First, let Zend Form define your HTML.  (Not the other way around).

For example, for your case you can define 3 classes:  `ParentContainer`, which contains  Collection of `DependentFeature` Fieldsets.  Each `DependentFeature` Fieldset contains Select element, and a Collection of `IndependentFeature` Fieldsets. Each `IndependentFeature` Fielset contains a single Select element.

Resulting HTML came out like this:

```
dependentFeatures[0][dependentFeature]
dependentFeatures[0][independentFeatures][0][independentFeature]
dependentFeatures[0][independentFeatures][1][independentFeature]
dependentFeatures[0][independentFeatures][2][independentFeature]

dependentFeatures[1][dependentFeature]
dependentFeatures[1][independentFeatures][0][independentFeature]
dependentFeatures[1][independentFeatures][1][independentFeature]
dependentFeatures[1][independentFeatures][2][independentFeature]
```

In other words, define the Collection of elements, nest them, and let Zend do the HTML work for you.

Using Zend Form Annotations you can do something like this:

```
/**
 * @Annotation\Name("parentContainer")
 * @Annotation\Hydrator({"type":"Zend\Hydrator\ClassMethods", "options": {"underscoreSeparatedKeys": false}})
 */
class ParentContainer
{

    /**
     * @Annotation\ComposedObject({
     * "target_object":"DependentFeature",
     * "is_collection":"true",
     * "options":{"count":2}
     * });
     *
     * @var DependentFeature[]
     */
    private $dependentFeatures;
}

/**
 * @Annotation\Name("dependentFeature")
 * @Annotation\Hydrator({"type":"Zend\Hydrator\ClassMethods", "options": {"underscoreSeparatedKeys": false}})
 * @Annotation\Instance("DependentFeature")
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Fieldset")
 */
class DependentFeature
{

    /**
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Dependent Feature:"})
     */
    private $dependentFeature;

    /**
     *
     * @Annotation\ComposedObject({
     * "target_object":"IndependentFeature",
     * "is_collection":"true",
     * "options":{"count":3}
     * });
     *
     * @var IndependentFeature[]
     */
    private $independentFeatures;
}

/**
 * *
 * @Annotation\Name("independentFeature")
 * @Annotation\Hydrator({"type":"Zend\Hydrator\ClassMethods", "options": {"underscoreSeparatedKeys": false}})
 * @Annotation\Instance("IndependentFeature")
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Fieldset")
 */
class IndependentFeature
{

    /**
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Number")
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Independent Feature:"})
     */
    private $independentFeature;
}
```

Create the form like so:

```
$form = (new AnnotationBuilder())->createForm(ParentContainer::class);
```

If you are not using Annotations, you can still build it as I mentioned above -> by nesting Collection of Fieldsets into you Collection of Fieldsets.

How exactly you name and nest your elements depends on your exact domain requirements.

Comment: I am thinking about the field names as features[0][dependent] and features[0][independent][] and likewise. What do you think, is it OK?

Comment: you probably can, it depends on your exact coded situation.  You can see what I did in updated answer.

Comment: Though, I haven't used annotation before, I will try that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can build your forms programmatically just the same.  See https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/collections/#creating-fieldsets